# Why it isnt adding the numbers?) (problem with return value)

Tags: python, return-value

I was trying to make a calculate but return doesnt work (Its an uncomplete code but iam an answer could solve it all )

```
def plus(num1, num2):
  return num1 + num2

symbols = {
"+":plus
  
}

num1 = int(input(": "))
num2 = int(input(": "))

symbol = input("symbol: ")

count = symbols[symbol]
count = (num1, num2)

print(count)
```

Comment: `symbols[symbol]` evaluates to the function object "plus" but the function isn't called. Additionally you overwrite "count" in the next line with a tuple.

Comment: Try `count = symbols[symbol](num1, num2)`.

Comment: A [mre] should describe actual and expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`symbols` contains a mapping from an operator to a function. You have to get this function, call it, and display the result.

```
def plus(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

symbols = {
    "+": plus,
}

num1 = int(input(": "))
num2 = int(input(": "))

symbol = input("symbol: ")

function = symbols[symbol]
result = function(num1, num2)

print(result)
```

As it is, this only handles the `+` operator. You might want to add some more operations and maybe an error handler for unknown symbols.